# How can I determine whether a PC has 1 CPU with 6 cores, or 6 CPUs (without opening the case)?

Tags: windows, cpu

When I log in remotely to a Windows box (using Windows Remote Desktop), I can see that the Computer Management applet shows 6 "Intel Xeon CPU" ***entries*** under "Processors", as shown below.

[image: Intel Xeon CPU]

(Based on ramhound's comment this amount of "Processors" is because of HT is not enabled.)

The Lenovo X1 Carbon laptop that I am using, on another hand, has the Intel's Core i5 CPU. Considering that this is a rather lightweight laptop, I would assume that this is just one CPU with 4 cores. The cores are listed in Computer Management applet as shown below.

[image: Intel's Core i5 CPU]

I would like to know if the remote computer has multiple processors or just 1 processor with multiple cores. It is not close by so I am not able to get to it and open up the case.

**Thus the question I wanted to ask is:**
How can it be determined if a Windows PC has multiple processors or just 1 processor with multiple cores, without opening the computer case?

Comment: Just look up your processor on AMD's or Intel's website.  You can also learn what sockets even support multiple processors.  In general a motherboard that accepts an Intel Core processors does not support multiple processors, a motherboard that accepts an Intel Xeon processor does support multiple processors.  Neither of those screenshots are multiple processors.

Comment: How do I know neither computer has more then a single processor.  First you only have 6 cores being reported in the first screenshot, a [Xeon E5645](http://ark.intel.com/products/48768/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5645-12M-Cache-2_40-GHz-5_86-GTs-Intel-QPI), has 6 cores.  A [i5-3427U](http://ark.intel.com/products/64903/Intel-Core-i5-3427U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_80-GHz) has 4 cores.

Comment: What you're seeing there are logical CPUs. It's slightly confusing to me because yours is showing up correct. You have a dual core CPU with two threads per core so it shows as 4. The Xeon should be showing 12 logical cores because it's a 6 core CPU with 2 threads each. Maybe you just didn't capture all of them. If you had two CPU's it would list 24 CPUs assuming it was a 6 core with two threads per core. .

Comment: I made a typo in my last comment, it has 2 cores, each core supports 2 threads.  First screenshot likewise isn't complete since 12 processors should be listed (or HT is disabled on the system).

Comment: Thanks ramhound & DrZoo. I will look into what you guys wrote. I did also update the 1st image to show that it was complete (Computer Management only shows 6 entries). So it's probably because HT is not enabled.